# App development

Tags: android, ios, iphone, html

I'm in a situation where I'm looking at building a company website and in-house app (for ipad/android) with basic functionality; pretty much just a portfolio. This is for the company I work for who (for many reasons, some of which I agree with, some I don't) don't particularly want to outsource this.

I've got a fairly basic knowledge of webdesign and would be able to put together a fairly decent website on my own however the app is what is causing me a slight headache as I'm not an expert at coding by any means. So my questions are:

1) Is it possible to build an app that isn't hosted on the app store? We have no requirement for people outside of the practice to have access to the app, so it'd only need to be an internal build. How (given that ios is so locked down) would I go about installing an app such as this, if I built one?

2) I've seen myriad app-building websites, some of which output code for both android and ios, others that (apparently) wrap them as some kind of hybrid so they run on either (though my understanding is that these may be refused by the app store?) and others that are just html5. Do you have any recommendations or experience of any of these sites?

3) I don't mind purchasing software to help get the job done. I'm in the process of mocking up a prototype in Adobe XD; but after that I'm fairly at a loss.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Chris.

Comment: If the app is only for your company users then it wouldn’t be accepted into the App Store anyway. An enterprise developer program membership is the appropriate approach. You can then distribute your app via an MDM or internal website. No apple approval is required for your app with the enterprise program.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes its possible to host the application outside of the app store. For this, you will need to register with Enterprise developer program (https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) . You need not deploy the apps to app store if you sign the app with an enterprise distribution certificate.
2. You can use the code got from these hybrid sites to build the application. I dont have recommendations now

Answer (score 0):

Glad you're getting started in XD! That's always a great way to prototype!
App development requires knowledge of languages like Swift, C#, Objective-C, C++.
 However since you are familiar with basic web languages (html, css, js) I would recommend looking into **Nativescript(https://www.nativescript.org/)**. 
It's a platform that allows you to build an actual native app using web languages. Read the docs (https://docs.nativescript.org/), watch some tutorial videos(https://courses.nativescripting.com/courses/nativescript-with-angular-getting-started-guide/lectures/2692194), and you'll be up shortly. It uses xml but you'll catch on pretty quick if you haven't used it yet.

Best of luck m8
Cheers!